# Azure Marketplace image not found

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I'm deploying Linux images using Terraform. To do that, we need to get the image *purchase plan* info from Azure Marketplace images (some require terms be accepted and some don't). Microsoft has an instructional doc on how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage. Great. The problem is that it does not work on some images some of our teams want to deploy and I can't see why, so I'm stuck not knowing how to deploy the images they've asked for.

Here's an example where finding the *purchase plan* info of a Checkpoint image works and I can accept the marketplace terms successfully. Notice the "plan" block information from the first command and then the terms showing as "accepted" in the second command:

```
scott@Azure:~$ az vm image show --urn checkpoint:check-point-cg-r81:mgmt-byol:latest
{
  "automaticOsUpgradeProperties": {
    "automaticOsUpgradeSupported": false
  },
  "dataDiskImages": [],
  "disallowed": {
    "vmDiskType": "None"
  },
  "extendedLocation": null,
  "features": null,
  "hyperVGeneration": "V1",
  "id": "/Subscriptions/5ff78d61-5262-4bd6-81fa-42d8723b8e3e/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus/Publishers/checkpoint/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/check-point-cg-r81/Skus/mgmt-byol/Versions/8100.900392.0710",
  "location": "westus",
  "name": "8100.900392.0710",
  "osDiskImage": {
    "operatingSystem": "Linux",
    "sizeInBytes": 107374182912,
    "sizeInGb": 100
  },
  "plan": {
    "name": "mgmt-byol",
    "product": "check-point-cg-r81",
    "publisher": "checkpoint"
  },
  "tags": null
}

scott@Azure:~$ az vm image terms show --urn checkpoint:check-point-cg-r81:mgmt-byol:latest
{
  "accepted": true,
  "id": "/subscriptions/5ff78d61-5262-4bd6-81fa-42d8723b8e3e/providers/Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering/offerTypes/VirtualMachine/publishers/checkpoint/offers/check-point-cg-r81/plans/mgmt-byol/agreements/current",
  "licenseTextLink": "https://mpcprodsa.blob.core.windows.net/legalterms/3E5ED_legalterms_CHECKPOINT%253a24CHECK%253a2DPOINT%253a2DCG%253a2DR81%253a24MGMT%253a2DBYOL%253a24U2R6YKHF2KWHXN7Y4Q4Q4OEKEYL6JZJCCZGIIGQBSB7FNDUBYTDIRQY6QPT5XMT7NGAH5XWH3LHSQY22URTFS3X7HZHQXZ3CIVJKC2Y.txt",
  "marketplaceTermsLink": "https://mpcprodsa.blob.core.windows.net/marketplaceterms/3EDEF_marketplaceterms_VIRTUALMACHINE%253a24AAK2OAIZEAWW5H4MSP5KSTVB6NDKKRTUBAU23BRFTWN4YC2MQLJUB5ZEYUOUJBVF3YK34CIVPZL2HWYASPGDUY5O2FWEGRBYOXWZE5Y.txt",
  "name": "mgmt-byol",
  "plan": "mgmt-byol",
  "privacyPolicyLink": "http://www.checkpoint.com/privacy",
  "product": "check-point-cg-r81",
  "publisher": "checkpoint",
  "retrieveDatetime": "2021-07-21T13:48:54.3464069Z",
  "signature": "R65W6K5QQIRJP7DUOIK26PND236FGY6YIVTOOJ3ZFZC2CRQGPNF5TA5BNANFJWTFRKFZULYKINVSJ2BIB2DDNRW5AMUS2N5KQR7YTBQ",
  "systemData": {
    "createdAt": "2021-07-21T13:48:54.417391+00:00",
    "createdBy": "5ff78d61-5262-4bd6-81fa-42d8723b8e3e",
    "createdByType": "ManagedIdentity",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2021-07-21T13:48:54.417391+00:00",
    "lastModifiedBy": "5ff78d61-5262-4bd6-81fa-42d8723b8e3e",
    "lastModifiedByType": "ManagedIdentity"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering/offertypes"
}
```

Now, using the exact same method, the one Microsoft prescribes in their own documentation, I can get an RHEL image, but then when I try to accept the terms it errors out that the image is not found. For all intents and purposes, the output of the first command has no appreciable difference from the Checkpoint image that worked as expected. Notice also I included the *location* information just to ensure the image was available in the intended region.

```
scott@Azure:~$ az vm image show -l westeurope --urn redhat:rhel-byos:rhel-lvm83:latest
{
  "automaticOsUpgradeProperties": {
    "automaticOsUpgradeSupported": false
  },
  "dataDiskImages": [],
  "disallowed": {
    "vmDiskType": "None"
  },
  "extendedLocation": null,
  "features": [
    {
      "name": "IsAcceleratedNetworkSupported",
      "value": "True"
    }
  ],
  "hyperVGeneration": "V1",
  "id": "/Subscriptions/5ff78d61-5262-4bd6-81fa-42d8723b8e3e/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westeurope/Publishers/redhat/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/rhel-byos/Skus/rhel-lvm83/Versions/8.3.20210409",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "8.3.20210409",
  "osDiskImage": {
    "operatingSystem": "Linux",
    "sizeInBytes": 68719477248,
    "sizeInGb": 64
  },
  "plan": {
    "name": "rhel-lvm83",
    "product": "rhel-byos",
    "publisher": "redhat"
  },
  "tags": null
}

scott@Azure:~$ az vm image terms show --urn redhat:rhel-byos:rhel-lvm83:latest
(BadRequest) Offer with PublisherId: 'redhat' and OfferId: 'rhel-byos' not found. Consider the following solutions: 1-Check to see if offer details are correct 2- If this offer is created recently, please allow up to 30 minutes for thisoffer to be available for purchase 3- If the offer is removed from the marketplace for new purchase. See similar offers here 'https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?page=1%26search=redhat%20rhel-byos'. CorrelationId '75335d2a-fc28-4e4c-acd3-ec2ea423f212'.
```

Clearly, it is the correct information. Yet, Azure can't find the image it literally just gave me the info for. What am I missing here? I'm not looking for workarounds or "use a different image" answers. I'm looking to understand what's going on to better deal with it head on, or deliver bad news with backed up data if need be. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the commands you have ran for both images in my subscription. I am able to see the Checkpoint image and its terms as well but not the RHEL-BYOS image terms.

[image]

[image]

**Checkpoint** offer is Public with `pay-as-you-go azure subscription` . That’s why its showing the terms for purchase . But the **RHEL-BYOS** `[bring-your-own-subscription (BYOS) (Red Hat Gold Image) model]` offer is Private.

**Requirements to use RHEL BYOS images:**

1. You must have access to  **Red Hat Cloud Access Program**. Enable your
   Red Hat subscriptions for Cloud Access at Red Hat
   Subscription-Manager. You need to have on hand the Azure
   subscriptions that are going to be registered for Cloud Access.
2. If the Red Hat subscriptions you enabled for Cloud Access meet the
   eligibility requirements, your Azure subscriptions are automatically
   enabled for Gold Image access.
3. After you finish the Cloud Access enablement steps, Red Hat
   validates your eligibility for the Red Hat Gold Images. If
   validation is successful, you receive access to the Gold Images
   within three hours.

**Reference:**

[Red Hat Enterprise Linux bring-your-own-subscription Azure images - Azure Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/redhat/byos)

[Red Hat Enterprise Linux Bring-Your-Own-Subscription Gold Images now Generally Available in Azure | Azure updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/rhel-gold-images-ga/)

Comment: Many thanks! Would be nice if they mentioned in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage documentation that there are exceptions like this. But now I know to watch out for them. Cheers!